# Need assistance in resolving this variation of shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

The below picture is the representation from the question which was asked to me during samsung interview. I had to write the program to find the minimum distance between I and M. There was an additional constraint that we can change one of the edges. For example, The edge FM can be moved to join edge L and M and the edge value will still be 4.

If you notice, the distance between I and M via I-> E -> F -> G -> M is 20. However, if we change one of the edges such that L to M edge value is 4 now. We have to move edge FM to join L and M now. By this method, the distance between I and M is 20.

An arbitrary edge u, v can be changed to u, t or t,v. It can not be changed to x,y. So one of the vertices in the edge has to be same.

Please find the picture below to illustrate the scenario -

[image]

So my problem is that I had to write the program for this. To find the minimum distance between two vertices, I thought of using Djikstra's algorithm. However , I as not sure how to take care of the additional constraint where I had the option of changing one of the vertices. If I could get some help to solve this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What does moving an edge mean exactly?

Comment: Does it mean that we can take an arbitrary edge `(u, v)` and change it into `(u, t)` or `(t, v)` for an arbitrary vertex `t`?

Comment: @kraskevich your understanding is correct. An arbitrary edge u, v can be changed to u, t or t,v. It can not be changed to x,y.

Answer (score 0):

1. If we move an edge `(A, B)`, the new end should be either the start `S` or the target `T` vertex (otherwise, the answer is not optimal).
2. Let's assume that we move the edge `(A, B)` and the new end is `T` (the case when it's `S` is handled similarly). We need to know the shortest path from `S` to `A` that doesn't use this edge (once we know it, we can update the answer with the `S->A->T` path).
3. Let's compute the shortest path from `S` to all other vertices using Dijkstra's algorithm.
4. Let's fix a vertex `A` and compute the two minimums of `dist[B] + weight(A, B)` for all `B` adjacent to `A`. Let's iterate over all edges adjacent to `A`. Let the current edge be `(A, B)`. If `dist[B] + weight(A, B)` is equal to the first minimum, let `d` be the second minimum. Otherwise, let `d` be the first minimum. We need to update the answer with `d + weight(A, B)` (it means that `(A, B)` becomes `(A, T)` now).

This solution is linear in the size of the graph (not counting the Dijkstra's algorithm run time).

To avoid code duplication, we can handle the case when the edge is redirected to `S` by swapping `S` and `T` and running the same algorithm (the final answer is the minimum of the results of these two runs).

Answer (score 0):

In the graph you've shown, the shortest path I see is `I -> E -> F -> M` with a length of 13.

[image]

Moving the edge `F -> M` so that it connects `L -> M` just makes things worse. The new shortest path is `I -> E-> F -> L -> M` with a length of 18.

[image]

The obvious answer is to move edge `F -> M` so that it connects `I` directly to `M`, giving a length of 4.

[image]

In other words, find the shortest edge that's connected to `I` or `M` and use it to connect `I` directly to `M`.

For future reference, it's highly unlikely that you'll be asked to implement Djikstra's algorithm from memory in an interview. So you need to look for something simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Actually if the value of F -> M is 9, the length 13 pass will not be valid. Also regarding the I -> M connect which you have tried in the last image is not valid because you can change one the vertices of the edge and not both. This is the constraint -

An arbitrary edge u, v can be changed to u, t or t,v. It can not be changed to x,y. So one of the vertices in the edge has to be same.

Comment: @user3276247 I changed the edge `F,M` to `I,M`. So one of the vertices (`M`) is the same.